# human body border detection using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

there is any body know any library that enable us to detect the body border or help me notify to body movment according to stream of images

Comment: This is a research level problem, you are unlikely to find a library on it at this moment in time.

Comment: There's no such thing as "C#.NET". It's just "C#".

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has such a library, called [Kinect](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Kinect-for-Xbox-360/product/C737B081).

However, I rather doubt they will license it to you.

There is not always a library for everything, especially if the problem is difficult to precisely define and on the cutting edge of technology.

Comment: this is right, but when you are working for difficult problem that need long programming time you always seach for library that simplify the work

Answer (score 2):

The basic element of this sort of processing is [Blob Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection).

There are examples in the wild for blob detection algorithms. There are libraries too, but I'm not sure about free ones.

See this:
http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/hands_gesture_recognition/

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at [open CV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) ? It's an open-source framework for image processing so it has a lot of helpful algorithms for contour detection, filtering, hull etc...

Also [OpenNI](http://openni.org) was just released. It's a framework for natural interaction. For now it's mostly set up to work with depth sensors such that Kinect and PrimeSense sensors, but in the not-so-far future it might be able to deal with other type of hardware, maybe standard video cameras...

Answer (score 2):

Link to [MSFT SDK site](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/kinectsdk/)

**Update:**

Just in from ZD.NET "Microsoft readies hobbyist Kinect development kit; promises commercial version later" [link](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-readies-hobbyist-kinect-development-kit-promises-commercial-version-later/8752)

**Prior Post**

The makers/OEM of the Kinect is PrimeSense.  They make both the kinect and an independent [devkit](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/12/10/primesense-releases-open-source-drivers-middleware-for-kinect/).  They recently released open source drivers that are compatible with both XBox's Kinect and the smaller DevKit.  You might as well get the drivers straight from the source.  I'm not sure what value a 3rd party library (openKinect) will offer.

Get the unified Kinect and DevKit drivers here: http://www.openni.org/  Windows and Unix support is available.

Comment: Related: [What UI Designs are a good fit for the Kinect](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/what-ui-designs-are-a-good-fit-for-the-kinect-primesense-devkit)